# Ubuntu server 16.04 apt-daily.service is necessary?

Tags: 16.04, server, services

On an Ubuntu 16.04 server by default the "apt-daily.timer" is enabled, it periodically calls "apt-daily.service" which calls /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily script.

My question is, on a server is this necessary at all? Is there any harm in permanently disabling the timer?

Comment: Read the script, and decide if you can do without the functionality. I suggest that you shouldn't.

Comment: @waltinator I read the script and I don't see it useful, why do you suggest I shouldn't?

Comment: Because it's a lightweight thingy installed by Canonical. It does some maintenance of your package database, and some handline of unattended-upgrades. It doesn't cost much to run, and should be far down a list of optimizations.

Comment: @waltinator reviewing the script for "some maintenance" but I actually don't see any meaningful benefit.  Also for a server I don't want any kind of "upgrades" that is not vetted first.  Also the server is behind a firewall and every day it goes crazy trying to access a few external servers (to download package info), the connections get blocked but it doesn't give up easy it attempts over 200+ times before giving up.